# How can I find the position of the user, based on earnings, but without listing all users into Memory

Tags: calculus, optimization, math-software

I have $200000$ users in database. I want to know the given user's position depending on his earnings, but without listing all the $200000$ users (explodes the memory of my small laptop)

So, given $200000$ users, and each users has an earning rank. My calculation so far was very simple:

Mist all $200000$ users sorted by rank and get the index of the given user. But this is not working anymore, because of RAM and obviously also not efficient way.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for stackoverflow.com

Comment: @angryavian yeah I have asked there also, but it is more mathematical problem than coding I think..

Comment: How is the user data stored? E.g. is it sorted in some way?

Comment: @JohnWhite yes, users can be sorted easily.

Comment: Use binary search then? Look up the earning of the user in a hashmap and then use bianry search on the sorted earnings list

Comment: @JohnWhite good idea, but doesn't it also grow if number of users grows?

Comment: Each search is $\Theta(\log n)$. Do you expect to add users to your database? How frequently vs searches? Can you amortize the cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient strategy will probably depend on what operation you expect you perform frequently.

If your userlist is static, why not just precompute the ranks for all the users? Now, each search is constant time.

If you expect many more insertions than searches, then you might be fine with using an unsorted array. This will give constant time insertions and $O(n)$ searches.

If you expect more searches, or around the same number of insertions and searches, then some sort of self balancing tree (like B-tree, AVL etc) will be best. This will give $O(\log n)$ insertions and $O(\log n)$ searches.

Comment: thanks John. makes sense. let me study this and implement